# Have a Class A in Class B when Class A doesn't have a default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

I have a Class A that is part of a library that I want to use in Class B. How do I put Class A as a private member in Class B if Class A doesn't have a default constructor? B needs to be inited with several variables and I would like to init it elsewhere if possible.

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

private:
    B b;
};
```

Comment: One option is `std::unique_ptr<B>`. But your question is very vague and thus too broad to write a good answer for.

Comment: Presumably your example has `A` and `B` swapped

Answer (score 3):

> How do I put Class A as a private member in Class B if Class A doesn't have a default constructor

You just call it's constructor in your constructor

```
A::A() 
: b( /* args go here */ ) ...
{
}
```

or if you cannot provide default arguments, you pass them through

```
A::A( /* args for b */ ) 
: b( /* pass args for b through */ ) ...
{
}
```

Comment: But how would you ***declare*** `b` in the class? The line `B b;` in OP's code will fail if there is no default constructor!

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica only if he didn't include the header for `B`. my example shows how to change the default constructor so that it compiles.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong - so long as the initialisation is as you specify it, then it *does* work!

Comment: And if you don't know or don't care what parameters you need to pass to `B`, there's [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the non-default constructor of `B` when you declare it as a member of your `A` class. This code compiles and runs as expected, but it's a very simple case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
    B() = delete; // This ENSURES we don't have a default constructor!
    B(int i, int j) : p{ i }, q{ j } { } // Constructor MUST have two int arguments!
    int p, q;
};

class A {
public:
public:
    A() : {}
    ~A() {}
    void setB(int i, int j) { b.p = i; b.q = j; } // Can be called later
    int getP() { return b.p; }
    int getQ() { return b.q; }
private:
    B b = B(0, 0); // LEGAL declaration of a "B" member: gives default (phoney) args/data
                   // ... which can be set later:e.g. using "setB(18,12)"
//  B bb; // ERROR - attempting to referencea deleted function!
};

int main()
{
    A a; // The "B" member (a.b) will have its "phoney" (default) values
    std::cout << a.getP() << " " << a.getQ() << std::endl;
    //...
    // 'later'...
    a.setB(18,12); //  
    std::cout << a.getP() << " " << a.getQ() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: The `=delete` is redundant. Declaring a non-default constructor already achieves the same goal.

Comment: @MSalters Indeed (although MSVC gives *slightly* different error messages with/without the `=delete`). However, I put it in primarily for emphasis/clarity.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, here might be a better way to put it. How can I say there will be a private member of Class B in Class A but not init the class with the constructor until later on because several values will be passed into Class A that will be used to init Class B?

Comment: @user1620479 OK, see edited answer! You will have to give some sort of *default* values to the `B` member (either as I have shown here, or in a modification to the answer given by @Thomas) but you can then set them later as and when you feel.